# Wordpress redirect post_id urls to full post url

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am using WordPress on a website, where I am using permalinks like

```
site.com/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

If a visitor visit `site.com/%post_id%/` it does not redirect to full post URL.

I have no idea how I can do that.

Edit: I am using Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Try `?p=%post_id%`

Why you use `post_id` and `postname` ? Why not just postname like this: `site.com/custom/%postname%` ?

Comment: Google news requires 3 digit in permalinks.